# Can TileMap children be referenced in the parent TileMap?

Tags: godot4

Try to wrap my head around the new way 2D Tiles are working in Godot 4.

Seems like in Godot 3, you could instance a TileMap scene as a child of a TileMap and all of tiles on the child were referenced on the parent. This is apparently not how Godot 4 works. While I can see the tiles of the child, they are not referenced in the parent. Is this how stacked TileMaps are supposed to work now?